# What is the difference between do-release-upgrade and the GUI "upgrade" option in Ubiquity?

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade, ubiquity

Is choosing this option in a live session different from running `do-release-upgrade` in a regular install? If so, how?

(Please ignore the version - I am actually upgrading from 12.04 to 16.04)

[image]

I have a lot of packages installed and services configured.

I'm somehow under the impression that at least the iso based method (ubiquity) more or less unpacks a fresh base system replacement and
then installs about the same set of packages, but most of the configuration is simply replaced (no merging etc.)

I would rather use the method that preserves as much of my configuration as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no other answer I'll write up what I gathered during the last few days trying both methods and various occasions in the past.

1. The Ubiquity/GUI Upgrade makes a note of what packages were installed previously. Then it proceeds to plop a fresh base system and mostly replacing the old one. After that the same set of packages is installed.
   Many /etc files and for example /var/www get reset during this process.

This method is not very nice for servers with custom configuration or data, but it is very fast and guarantees a properly modernized system.

2. The `do-release-upgrade` method runs from inside the system. It executes some custom transition scripts, but mostly it is `apt-get upgrade` but to the next LTS system. If you are 2 LTS releases behind like I was, you will need to run it twice. Differences between default configuration files are detected as the packages are installed.

If all goes well many custom configurations are be preserved or are pointed out by the upgrade and need a small amount of manual work each.

The downsides are that the process takes a long time and may need manual intervention multiple times along the way. It may get technical trying to figure out the differences between old and the new config files. Also the result can be a weird crossing between the latest Ubuntu technology and old packages and configurations carried over.

Some notes on running `do-release-upgrade` and graphical sessions.: Running this from a graphical user interface may be a bad idea. The graphical session gets tormented in various ways when packages get upgraded from underneath it. Wisely the `do-release-upgrade` wraps it self in a `screen` session. (I had trouble reconnecting to the `screen` session. Luckily I also had a `tmux` running on top of that. and after getting an older version of `tmux` I was able to resume from a text console.)